# Пока не будет верно введена цифра..софт не будет работать дальше

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter digit: ");
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int n1 = s1.nextInt();
if (n1 == 1)
{
    System.out.print("1234555555");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("error");
}
```

мне надо, чтобы если я ввел 123656543544, то написать типа Error, enter again...

Comment: про циклы знаете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а причем тут циклы?

Comment: Притом, что слово "пока" подразумевает цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> **Пока** считанная строка не равна кодовому слову
>     Выводить: Ошибка, попробуйте ещё
> Вывести: ок
> ```

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!s1.nextLine().equals("Password")) {
  System.out.println("Error, try again");
}

System.out.println("ok");
```

---

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String inp;
do {
  inp = s1.nextLine();
  if (inp.equals("exit") || inp.equals("quit")) {
    System.exit(1);
  }
} while (!inp.equals("Password"));

System.out.println("ok");
```

Comment: как мне написать типа if(s1==7) То тогад(на c# ) Environment.Exit(-1);
как мне эту строку на java переписать?

Comment: а Почему он мне подчеркивает Exit ?
The method Exit(int) is undefined for the type Environment

Comment: Если в Main, можно просто `return 1;`

Comment: не идет не так и не так

Comment: сработало только так:
`Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
 if (!s1.nextLine().equals("7"))
 {
     System.exit(-1);
 }
 else
 {
     System.out.print("error");
     s1.close();
 }`

Comment: У `Java` нет метода `Exit`, есть только `exit`. С маленькой буквы. не путать `с#`, где практически все методы начинаются с заглавной буквы.